# Show all values of a multi File field sorted by upload time

Tags: views, files, entities

I have a content type with a File field that allows multiple values. What's the best way to display these files as a list ordered by upload time rather than delta but still using the file descriptions?

The Manage Display options don't really give any options for sorting the list on the node display.

I tried creating a File View using the content id in the url as a contextual filter, while this does let me sort by date I can't seem to use the file description in the output.

Is there a way to get file descriptions in File views or should I look at writing a custom formatter for the node display?

Answer (score 0):

I found the module Extended File Field does exactly what I want.

https://www.drupal.org/project/extended_file_field

[image: File display optiond]